# Is it possible to escape & while loading xml?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an & character in one of the xml nodes as below.

```
<dependents>9 & 5</dependents>
```

When I try to load the file as below, it is giving an error  "An error occured while parsing EntityName.". Is it possible to escape this character and load successfully? Thank you.

```
 m_InputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(InputFile))
        {
            m_InputXMLDoc.Load(InputFile);
        }
```

Comment: Because the file is not valid XML. You could attempt to run it through a "fix up" stream first or ... use a "lenient" (often HTML-based) parser ... or, best, fix it at the source.

Comment: You could manually read the file element by element.  Otherwise using the XmlDocument.Load() cannot be escaped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XML is invalid.
You need to change it to `&amp;`.

Comment: _Someone_ needs to change it to `&amp;`. Likely the supplier of the "xml" file should do that.

Answer (score 6):

Use a CDATA section

```
<dependents><![CDATA[9 & 5]]></dependents>
```